# Bootstrap 3.0.2 not styling forms by default

Tags: jquery, css, forms, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

On bootstrap documentation:

> Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling.

If you look in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4f8FR/7/ You will notice that the regular forms are not getting styled at all.

On a project (I have a lot of forms) I added the .form-control class via jQuery to all inputs, but it's not working at all on Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('input[type="text"]').addClass('form-control'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the jQuery code should work, Please `update firefox to latest version`

Comment: The code actually work, because I get the fields styled, but they don't show it's value and when you click on them you cannot type.

Comment: The jquery that applies the class to inputs work in terms of styling but when you click on them in FF or IE inputs aren't working at all.
The file triggering that is cpr-scripts.js

Comment: Yes, latest. IE was v11. Did you get the link to the site?

Comment: I fixed @Delphian, it was a css code I had (the padding):
`input[type="text"], textarea{
 font-family: 'font' !important;
 font-size: 14px !important;
 padding: 20px 15px !important;
}`
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You haven't loaded jQuery on the fiddle - [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f8FR/5/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```

Could it be the same in your actual code?

Comment: Sorry, yes I forgot to, but on my code is loading latest from Google CDN